# Mac Osx Yosemite localhost document path errors

Tags: macos, apache, laravel, localhost

Working in Yosemite's localhost for a few months now. Previously I went through a simple configuration tutorial where the URL would be localhost/~username/project/public. Never really bothered me since I was just messing around with some simple sites. I recently ran into a problem with Laravel and Angular and its been suggested that my URL having the public in it was causing my routes to fail.

So I edited /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jeffcairoli/Sites/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jeffcairoli/Sites/time-tracker-2/public"
    ServerName time-tracker-2.local
    <directory "/Users/jeffcairoli/Sites/time-tracker-2/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow, deny
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In /etc/hosts I added:

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
255.255.255.255  broadcasthost
::1              localhost
fe80::1%lo0      localhost
127.0.0.1        time-tracker-2.local
```

In /etc/apache2/http.conf I uncommented the virtual hosts and vhost loadmodule.

When I visit time-tracker-2.com I am directed right to apache's It works! page.

I cannot figure out what I need to change to actually get it to point into my projects public folder so my laravel routes will take over. If anyone has any pointers or a better way to get my urls working please let me know. This issue is starting to drive me nuts.

**Update After making the changes to the vhosts and hosts files that I added here, I now get a 403 Forbidden when i visit localhost or time-tracker-2.local. localhost/~jeffcairoli brings me to the listing of all my files in my sites folder. Im not too sure if I am looking at this wrong or something. I've always had an issue getting these to work. Haven't been able to get any of the typical 403 fixes to work there but I think that tells me that at least its recognized my changes since the urls are actually giving me a response.

Comment: Are you using XAMPP by any chance?

Comment: No just using the built in localhost

Answer (score 1):

Adding another VirtualHost before that for localhost to be the default should fix your problem. Just try adding the following before your `time-tracker2.com` entry.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jeffcairoli/Sites/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Ok so I added that and now I get a forbidden 403 when I try to go to localhost or time-tracker-2. I've followed a couple different set up guides about giving apache permission to access the files but I'm still getting a 404. 
In /etc/hosts do I need to add a new line for the localhost that you had me add in the vhosts file or are the preexisting 127.0.0.1 localhost lines sufficient?

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in the ServerName, it should be just localhost. Mind updating your post with your full vhosts conf file and /etc/hosts? I replicated the same vhost entries and hosts entry and it should be working fine.

Comment: Sure. I added my current vhosts and host files

Comment: Is localhost/~username/project/public still accessible, or are you getting 403 there as well now?

Comment: No if I go through the index at localhost/~username the pages will load but anything setup under the vhosts file is still giving me 403.